# Changing object property from function

Tags: javascript, object, resize

I am learning javascript... sorry...

Example:

```
var car = {
    brand : 'fiat'
}
$(window).resize(function(){
    car.brand = 'audi';
})

console.log(car.brand)
```

How can I get 'audi'?

Comment: You cannot get `audi`. `console.log()` is run at load time but you change the value just when you resize your window.... stop to hope to see it and try something else!

Answer (score 1):

The value does change! But, let's back up a bit.
According to jQuery's API Documentation about the [resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

> The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the
>   browser window changes:

`car.brand` won't be set to `'audi'` until the resize event is triggered. The script will continue to execute until the end and log the initial value for `car.brand` because the window hasn't been resized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I keep getting 'fiat'. Please, check: https://jsfiddle.net/luiscornejo/neem5yah/

Comment: This is a great answer. (I'd upvote twice if I could.) @LuisCornejo, the code inside your function isn't run until the window resizes. At the point where the `console.log` is fired, the window has not resized and therefore the value of `car.brand` hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a timeline of events:

1. `car` is defined with `brand` of `'fiat'`.
2. A [listener is added](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the `window`'s `resize` event. (***The function is not run here so `car.brand` remains the same as when it was defined.***)
3. The value of `car.brand` is logged to the console. (At this point, it is `'fiat'`.)

If you want to log the value: `'audi'`, you can use something like this:

```
var car = {
    brand : 'fiat'
}
$(window).resize(function() {
    car.brand = 'audi';
    console.log(car.brand); // It will log 'audi' here.
})

console.log(car.brand) // It will log 'fiat' here.
```

The log inside the `resize` function will not run until the window is resized, so you will see something like this in your console:

```
'fiat'
```

and then after you resize your window:

```
'fiat'
'audi'
```

Comment: Exactly @jsve! That is the question. In the example, the only way to run the console.log is from inside the window.resize(), I know. But I want to change the value of object property from the resize event. I'm working in a plugin of slider and I have done objects for differents viewports (through matchmedia) that allow changing the configuration of columns,... It works perfect, but when the window resize I need reload de page, and that is bad. http://luiscornejo.com/cornislider3

Comment: Here's my suggestion. Create a function which gets the height and width of the window (viewport) and adjusts the display accordingly. Then call this function when the page loads and when the page resizes.

Comment: Thanks jsve, I try it! (Sorry, I wanted change a property of an object outside the function being inside the function)

Comment: @LuisCornejo, did you create a function that contains everything after "Valores configurables" and then run that when the window loads (you can just call the function at the end) and when the window resizes?

Comment: I am grateful for your interest. And yes, I tried it. I put the conditionals that contains the object "config" and the properties with matchmedia condicions inside a function.  At the end of this conditionals I called the function, and also from window resize function. The problem is the same, the object and the properties don't be outside the new function, only inside, getting undefined when the code call a property of object.